# CCK select list and default values from array without writing custom module

Tags: 6, entities

For my CCK select list options, I did:

```
//just making up firstName field to simplify example
$sql = "SELECT uid,firstName FROM users";
db_query($sql);
while($row = db_fetch_object($result)) {
  $uids[$row->uid] = $row->firstName;
}
return $uids;
```

This returns something like:

```
'1' => 'joe'
'2' => 'bob'
'3' => 'sarah'
```

Now in CCK, how do I programmatically set the the logged in user's id to be the default selected from the select list?  Furthermore, CCK's example of a default return value makes no sense to me:

```
return array(
  0 => array('value' => value for value),
  // You'll usually want to stop here. Provide more values
  // if you want your 'default value' to be multi-valued:
  1 => array('value' => value for value),
  2 => ...
);
```

I know I can do this with hook_form_alter, but I am trying this WITHOUT writing any custom module so I can learn CCK and make it easy for my future devs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
global $user;
return array(
  0 => array( 'value' => $user->uid )
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the right syntax that CCK wants.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, my bad... check the edits!

Answer (score 1):

What CCK is looking for is a keyed array as you COULD have multiple values selected/selectable for the field, but in this case I am thinking you have only one, or the '0'th value.  Thus, if all you are looking for is the current user id, you could return it this way as the default value:

```
global $user;
$vu=array('value' => $user->uid);

return array(0 => $vu);
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is good to know in treating an individual value